# Does the Nest Developer Program allow clients to be open source?

Tags: open-source, nest-api

The title of this question says it all: I'm interested in writing a Nest client, but I'd like to make it open source.

Is this permitted under the Nest developer agreement?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licencing, not a specific programming problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing arrangements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't prohibited, but you need to be very careful with how OAuth is handled. Posting sensitive information (for example client secrets) will likely get those clients suspended.

That said, there are sample applications published as open source on the Nest Developer Program site itself https://developer.nest.com/docs/topics/sample-code, you just need to create your own client to plug in to the samples.